# uglify not able to distinguish between folder and file ending in .js

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I want to uglify all the .js files in a directory using grunt. But the problem is, there are folders ending in .js. I believe grunt-uglify is not able to distinguish between the folder ending in .js. Also, there are .js files in .js folder. Can someone tell me what to do? I am very new to this

My Project structure ->

MyProject/app/assets/lib/amcharts/dist/amcharts/plugins/export/libs/FileSaver.js

where FileSaver.js is a folder which contains .js files. It is failing at FileSaver.js

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "App",
  "description": "App",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
  "express": "3.x",
  "grunt-contrib-copy": "^1.0.0"
},
 "devDependencies": {
   "grunt": "^0.4.5",
   "grunt-cli": "^1.2.0",
   "grunt-contrib-clean": "^1.1.0",
   "grunt-contrib-copy": "^1.0.0",
   "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^1.1.0",
   "grunt-contrib-requirejs": "~0.4.1",
   "grunt-contrib-symlink": "^1.0.0",
   "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^2.3.0",
   "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0",
   "grunt-exec": "^3.0.0",
   "grunt-git": "^0.3.7",
   "grunt-text-replace": "^0.4.0",
   "jasmine-core": "^2.8.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt travis --verbose"
 }
  }
```

My GruntFile.js

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({

    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    uglify :{
        files :{
            'build/dest.js': 'app/*.js'
        }
    }

});
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
```

};

Comment: Well, `app/*.js` matches anything that ends in `.js` (also, please use the search before you ask a new question).

Comment: You probably shouldn't have folders who's names end with `.js`; its confusing convention. Instead, try using a hyphen or nesting folders (`dest.js` becomes `dest-js` or `dest/js`)

Comment: First of all it's better to avoid .js for folder names. It's not the best practice. Just try adding 'app/**/*.js'. But I'm not sure this will work. But give it a try.

Comment: @FelixKling The question you are referring to involves ignoring such folders. I am trying to access that folder which contains the actual .js file

Comment: Whoops, ok.....

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, *(as noted in the comments)*, naming folders with a `.js` suffix is bad practice. You really need to change your projects folder nomenclature if you can. However, if that's not feasible, it is possible to get [grunt-contrib-uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) to ignore folders whose name ends in `.js`.

This entails dynamically generating the configuration object for the `uglify` Task via the use of a custom helper function *(namely `configureUglify` in the example gist below)*. The resultant configuration will be very similar to [this example](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#basic-compression) shown in the `uglify` documentation, whereby each `.js` file is defined in an Array. The main difference being is that instead of manually defining each filepath we dynamically generate it instead.

---

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    uglify : {
      // <--  // Intentionally empty, will be auto generated.
    }
  });

  /**
   * Helper function creates config object for uglify Task.
   */
  function configureUglify() {
    var glob = 'app/**/*.js',
      config = {},
      jsFiles = [];

    grunt.file.expand({ filter: 'isFile' }, glob).forEach(function (filePath) {
      jsFiles.push(filePath)
    });

    config.target = {
      files : {
        'build/dest.js' : jsFiles
      }
    }

    grunt.config('uglify', config);
    grunt.task.run(['uglify']);
  }

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

  grunt.registerTask('uglifyJs', configureUglify);
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglifyJs']);
};
```

---

**Notes**

1. The `configureUglify` helper function *(above)* utilizes [grunt.file.expand](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.expand) to iterate over each path found via the `glob` pattern `'app/**/*.js'`.
2. The `{ filter: 'isFile' }` part ensures that only paths to files ending in `.js` are processed (i.e. The folder `FileSaver.js` or any other folder whose name ends in `.js` are simply ignored ).
3. The [globbing](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns) pattern `'app/**/*.js'` will find all `.js` files stored in the `app` directory, including any found in sub-folders. If you want to *uglify* only the files stored in folder named `FileSaver.js` then change the `glob` pattern to:

```js
var glob = 'app/assets/lib/amcharts/dist/amcharts/plugins/export/libs/FileSaver.js/**/*.js'
```

4. Running `$ grunt` via your commandline using the `Gruntfile.js` example gist provided will result in a single file named `dest.js` saved to the `build` folder/directory.

---

**Important**

When combining multiple files into one single `.js` file (e.g. `dest.js`) the order in which the files are combined is often important to ensure the application functions correctly. So you may find that explicitly defining the paths Array in your `Gruntfile.js`, (instead of dynamically as above, which does not guarantee the correct order), better achieves your requirements. For example:

```js
grunt.initConfig({
  uglify: {
    my_target: {
      files: {
        'build/dest.js': [
           'app/assets/lib/foo.js',
           'app/assets/lib/amcharts/dist/amcharts/plugins/export/libs/baz.js',
           'app/assets/lib/amcharts/dist/amcharts/plugins/export/libs/FileSaver.js/a.js',
           'app/assets/lib/amcharts/dist/amcharts/plugins/export/libs/FileSaver.js/b.js',
           'app/assets/lib/amcharts/dist/amcharts/plugins/export/libs/FileSaver.js/c.js'
        ]
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Also, typically the single resultant uglified/minified `.js` file is named with a `.min.js` suffix - this is just general good practice. So you may want to consider changing `'build/dest.js'` to `'build/dest.min.js'`

Comment: When I run the grunt command, I am getting this error ->
app/shared/api.service.js failed.
Warning: Uglification failed.
Unexpected token: name (nodeResolve).

Comment: My guess is that the file is written in ES6 and probably `imports` a [ES6 class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes). However, `grunt-contrib-uglify` (`master`) handles ES5 only. The  [harmony](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify/tree/harmony) branch supports ES6+. Which version of JavaScript does your project utilize? Also please note that this issue has nothing to do with your original post; "_uglify not able to distinguish between folder and file ending in .js_", which my answer provides a solution to.

Comment: See this [issue](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify/issues/491) in the  `grunt-contrib-uglify` github repo for further info on how to install the harmony version.... `npm install git://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify.git#harmony --save-dev`